# use get parameters in DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile()

Tags: php, domdocument

I want to load an url like this using `DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile()`: `http://www.domain.com/dir/page?param1=235235&param2=2345`, but it gives this error, even though the page exists:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(http://www.domain.com/dir/page?param1=235235&amp;param2=2345): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Use curl then use domdocument

Comment: Here is an escaped & in your url. The message says that it can not open the url. Validate it. Sometimes additional headers (user agent) are needed.